# forcing vertical size of savebox to equal page height

Tags: boxes

Is there a better way of generating a `\savebox` whose dimensions are equal to the paper dimensions than sticking in a `\strut` of length equal to the page height (width is an argument to the `\savebox` itself).

Comment: A strut is certainly not necessary, but unless we know quite what you want to use the whole page for, it'll be hard to give you a good answer.  Answers will range from setting the height of the box directly to using `TikZ` to create a node that covers the entire page.

Comment: a `savebox` is horizontal box so the height is the content height. You can try `\sbox\sb{\parbox[t][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{some text}}`

Comment: Yes, perhaps a parbox is easier.   @A.Ellett: I just want a savebox of the given dimensions that I can then fill with whatever I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `lrbox`es and `minipage`s, you can save your content to a box.  Then once saved, you can resize the box.  Keep in mind, while the dimensions of the box are changed, the typesetting remains the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
%% open the dimensions of the page a bit
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\newsavebox\aebox
%% set fbox parameters to facilitate seeing how dimensions are changed.
\setlength\fboxsep{-0.4pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}\aebox
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
    This is just an example of a box of certain dimensions that can later be
    reassigned.
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

Hello
\fbox{\usebox\aebox}
\ht\aebox\dimexpr\baselineskip*2\relax
\dp\aebox\dimexpr\textheight-\baselineskip*2\relax
\fbox{\usebox\aebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the above doesn't quite do what you want.  You could take @HarishKumar 's approach and set the geometry of the page so that the margins are all `0pt`.  In that case, in the above example, if you set

```
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
```

you'll get

[image]

But what if you don't want to set the margins to `0pt`?

Assuming that the margins are set to `0.5in`
you could try something like

```
\raisebox{\dimexpr0.5in+\baselineskip+<some dimension>\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\fbox{\usebox\aebox}}
```

But then it's difficult (as least for me), to figure out how exactly to set `<some dimension>` so that your box is properly placed.

In that case, you might want to load `tikz` (which is also *optionally* called when loading the `tcolorbox` package).  This is what you could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% open the dimensions of the page a bit
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\newsavebox\aebox
%% set fbox parameters to facilitate seeing how dimensions are changed.
\setlength\fboxsep{-0.4pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.4pt}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}\aebox
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
    This is just an example of a box of certain dimensions that can later be
    reassigned.
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\hspace*{3.5in} Hello \fbox{\usebox\aebox}

%% setting the dimensions of the box
\ht\aebox\dimexpr\baselineskip\relax
\dp\aebox\dimexpr\paperheight-\baselineskip\relax
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west,fill=orange!20] at ($(current page.north west)+(0.5in,0)$) {\fbox{\usebox\aebox}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tcolorbox` that offers `height` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}  %% just for demo
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.5\textwidth,height=\paperheight]
    \lipsum[1-2]
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]